# Solving 3D knapsack using bruteforce in Java

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

I want to solve a 3-dimesional knapsack problem.

I got a number of boxes with a different width, height, length and value. I got a specified space and I want to put the boxes into that space, such that I will get the optimal profit. I would like to do it with using bruteforce.

I'm programming in Java.
I tried to do it with recursion, so:

```
public void solveBruteforce(double freeX, double freeY, double freeZ) {
   for(int i = 0; i < numOfBoxes; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < BoxObject.numOfVariations; j++) {
         if(possible to place box) {
            place(box);
            add(value);
            solveBruteforce(newX, newY, newZ);
         }
      }
   }
   remove(box);
   remove(value);
}
```

But I will get the problem that each line has a different free x, y and z.

Could someone help me to find another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is, use an octree to keep track of where things are in the space. Occupancy tree is a 3D 4-out-degree tree, with occupancy flags at every node, dividing your space into a place that is efficient to search over. This would be useful if you want to use some kind of heuristic search to place the boxes, and even if you are trying all possibilities. It can shortcut the forbidden (crowded) placements.

Brute force will take a *long* time. But if that's what you want you need to define an ordering for trying out permutations of placements.

Since you will need many iterations, recursion is not so great since you will get a stack overflow.

A first-*draft* alternative would involve a greedy algorithm. Take the box that maximizes your profit (say, the largest), place that, then take the next largest box, and find the best fit for that, and so on.

But, say you wanted to try all possible combinations:

```
def maximize_profit(boxes,space):
    max_profit = 0
    best_fits = list()
    while(Arranger.hasNext()):
        a_fit,a_profit = Arranger.next(boxes,space)
        if (a_profit == max_profit):
            best_fits.append(a_fit)
        elif (a_profit > max_profit):
            max_profit = a_profit
            best_fits = [ a_profit ]
    return best_fits, max_profit
```

For ideas on how to define the Arranger, think about choosing #{box} slots from #{space} possibilities, respecting arrangements that are identical w.r.t. symmetry. Alternately maybe  a "flood fill" method will give you ideas.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your answer. I know the greedy algorithm, but I don't understand what you are saying about the occupancey tree. Is there another way of doing it. Or if I size the problem down to 3 or 4 boxes with a given length, height and width?

Comment: @user1110725 Octree just saves checking every point for occupancy each time. Only have to check log(points) of them. Hmm, if you want 3 or 4 boxes that you can fully define by giving only x,y,z, then they will have max 3 sizes of faces, and if you only allow  parallel-to-axis layouts then 6 possible rotations for each box. So as long as the space is not *so* much larger than the boxes that there are *lots* of location choices, that will be easier. Just make sure you rotate through all cases for each box. And go through the (if it's 4 boxes) 24 orders. Also, google "optimal box packing".